Sequelize slugify is not updating slug when source field is changed
I'm building web app with node js + express + sequelize backend. I created rest-api with 3 collections: goals, cashflows, accounts. For each collection there are CRUD operations available. When I send POST request to create account it sets slug automatically using name field that I provided in request body. When I send PATCH request to update account's name slug does not change.
Code:
controller patch action:
const update = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const userID = req.user.id;
    const slug = req.params['slug'];
    const account: Account = {
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description,
        balance: req.body.balance,
        userID,
    }

    try {
        const result = await accountService.update({ userID, slug }, account);
        res.status(httpCodes.CREATED_RESOURCE).json(result);
    } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof AppError) {
            if (err.code === appCodes.NOT_FOUND)
                return res.status(Number(httpCodes.NOT_FOUND)).json(getJsonError(err));

            return res.status(httpCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json(getJsonError(err));
        }

        throw err;
    }
}

account service update function:
const update = async (options: UpdateOptions<AccountBase>, newAccount: Account): Promise<object> => {
    let { slug, userID } = options;

    try {
        const result = await accounts.findOne({ slug, userID });

        if (!result) {
            throw new NotFoundError(`Account ${slug} not found!`, appCodes.NOT_FOUND, '', true);
        }

        const account: Account = {
            name: newAccount.name || result.name,
            description: newAccount.description || result.description,
            balance: newAccount.balance || result.balance,
            userID: result.userID,
        }

        const result2 = await accounts.update(options, account);

        return result2;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}

sequelize schema for account + sequelize slugify plugin:
class AccountModel extends Model<Account> { }

AccountModel.init(
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false,
        },
        slug: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true,
        },
        description: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(1000),
        },
        balance: {
            type: DataTypes.REAL,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 0
        },
        userID: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    },
    {
        sequelize: db,
        modelName: 'Account',

    },
);

SequelizeSlugify.slugifyModel(AccountModel, {
    source: ['name'],
    overwrite: true,
});

model update function:
const update = async (options: UpdateOptions<AccountBase>, newAccount: Account): Promise<object> => {
    const { slug, userID, balance, description, id, name } = options;
    const where: any = {
        userID,
        slug,
    }

    if (balance) where.balance = balance;
    if (description) where.description = description;
    if (id) where.id = id;
    if (name) where.name = name;

    const queryOptions: Sequelize.UpdateOptions<Account> = {
        where: where,
    }

    try {
        await AccountModel.update(newAccount, queryOptions);
        return {
            message: 'Successfully updated account'
        }
    } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof BaseError) {
            throw new DatabaseError(err.message, dbCodes.ACCOUNT_UPDATE_ERR, err, true);
        }

        throw err;
    }
}

I looked at Sequelize Slugify issues on github, I viewed my code a few times and I can't figure out what is wrong.
